# elastic search: how to choose random distinct listings not distinct based on unique identifier of the document?

Tags: elasticsearch, unique, distinct, aggregation, cardinality

We have ES document of car-stocks that has following key-value pairs:

```
{
  "stockid":1,
  "car": "bmw"
  "dealerid": "d1"
},
{
  "stockid":2,
  "car": "audi"
  "dealerid": "d1"
},,
{
  "stockid":3,
  "car": "mercedes"
  "dealerid": "d1"
},,
{
  "stockid":4,
  "car": "bentley"
  "dealerid": "d2"
},
{
  "stockid":5,
  "car": "range rover"
  "dealerid": "d1"
}
```

There are thousand of such documents. The document contains many more fields, I have just over-simplified it and specified only the necessary fields to understand the query.

We want to pick 'N' stocks randomly based on dealerid. For example, if someone queries on the above stocks document, there is equal probability of getting stock of "d1" or "d2" despite dealer "d1" have 4 stocks and "d2" has only 1. There are thousand such documents with thousand of dealers too from "d1" to "dXXXX" and this list is constantly changing.

Can someone help me to write this elastic query?

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to restructuring your index? You could use a [Parent Child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-parent-field.html) approach. `dealers` are parents, `stocks` are children, then you can easily use a random seed to query over dealers or stocks per dealer since the documents will be unique.

You *should* be able to replicate your current queries by querying over the `stocks` children since you can still access the parent fields in a denormalized way using `has_parent` (or `has_child` the opposite direction)

PUT /cars

```
{
    "mappings" : {
        "dealers" : { },
        "stocks" : {
            "_parent" : {
                "type" : "dealers"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GET /cars/dealers/_search

```
{
    "query" : {
        "function_score" : {
            "functions" : [
                {
                    "random_score" : {
                        "seed" : "randawefawfm" // generate this
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size" : N
}
```